# WPF how to show an Image.Source (BitmapSource) pixel position?

Tags: wpf, coordinates, pixel, mousemove

Let's suppose I've got an image which shows its source in a scaled way, how could i use a
MouseMove event to show in a label or textblock the pixel position in which the cursor is?

(I need the pixel coordinates not the coordinates of the image relative to its size)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find out the actual pixel height and width from the ImageSource.

```
    ImageSource imageSource = image.Source;
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = (BitmapImage) imageSource ;
```

Now since you got the image displayed in Image control. You can easily map the mouse position to the Pixel scale.

```
pixelMousePositionX = e.GetPosition(image).X * bitmapImage.PixelWidth/image.Width;
pixelMousePositionY = e.GetPosition(image).Y * bitmapImage.PixelHeight/image.Height;
```

Have fun

[Jobi Joy](http://jobijoy.blogspot.com)

Comment: Thanks for the help, your solution seems to be simple and efficient.

Thank you very much!

Comment: better to use `mage.ActualWidth` instead of `mage.Width`

Answer (score 3):

If your Image's XAML as follow:

```
 <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
            BorderThickness="3" 
            BorderBrush="BlueViolet">
        <Image x:Name="Image_Box" 
               VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
               Source="8.jpg"
               Stretch="Uniform"
               MouseMove="ImageBox_OnMouseMove"
               />
    </Border>
```

Maybe  the `Image` control's width is double.Nan ,So we need to use `ActualWidth` property. so the Code  as follow:

```
private void ImageBox_OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageSource imageSource = Image_Box.Source;
        BitmapSource bitmapImage = (BitmapSource)imageSource;
        TextBoxCursor_X.Text =( e.GetPosition(Image_Box).X * bitmapImage.PixelWidth / Image_Box.ActualWidth).ToString();
        TextBoxCursor_Y.Text = (e.GetPosition(Image_Box).Y * bitmapImage.PixelHeight / Image_Box.ActualHeight).ToString();
    }
```

Comment: You're right, the previous answer to the post the Image width is returning NaN

Comment: My numbers are way off. I have it VAlignment=Top HAlignment=Center Stretch=Uniform. I have the image inside a Grid. Do you guys suggest anything?